# Create tableview like Facebook timeline... iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, tableview

I want to create an app like Facebook timeline, so want to know that do anyone know how to create tableview like Facebook timeline, that it loads cell limited number of cell at once and automatically when we move to bottom of timeline?

I want to create lazy loading tableview that automatically load new cells when user goes to the bottom of tableview.

Comment: @TeodorCarstea if u have any problem with my avatar than it is ur problem, and you dont want to help me, then y u wasting your precious time to answer.

Comment: the thing that you want is called "Pagination". Google for pagination techniques in iOS tableview loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a quick terse answer will be:
Load the first few cells of the timeline when the app loads at first. Then when the user starts scrolling, load those cell numbers, depending on "how much" the user has scrolled (use a Gesture Recognizer to calculate this), so that you can load only those cells.

For example, if one cell's height is 40 points. If the user scrolls such that the screen shows from 200 points (i.e. the 'x' value at the top left corner of the screen), then load from cell number 6 (because the user has scrolled past 5 cells  i.e. 200/40 = 5).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, i will surely try in this ways, thanks for help.